# smbtree sometimes list the newtwork tree and sometime is doesnt?

Tags: samba, smb

> why smbtree sometimes list the network tree and sometimes is doesn't ?

```
smbtree
LIST all computers on network  -- Good
```

Now again i tires on same machine without making any changes in configuration

```
smbtree
BLANK   --Bad why?
```

When i run smbtree on my Linux terminal some times it  is **good** it list all the network,domain and share but some time its **bad** it doesn't list any things?

**Note: I have not made any changes in smb.config file**

why some time its bad?
What does smbtree return when its fail?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it apparently has nothing to do with programming. Perhaps [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You firewall is blocking the port 445 and 139 which is used by smb .Configure you iptables to get access to this port and you will be good.